# What is best practice to login with linked-in from iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, linkedin-api

I am new in iOS. I write the application that has the Linked-In login in it. What is the best way from the follows to do Linked-In login from oOS app:

1) login with url-scheme (like in Facebook login)

2) login from the web view (like it is explained here: 
[Linkedin - iOS - Detect user cancel login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105908/linkedin-ios-detect-user-cancel-login))

3) to build login GUI by myself (where can I read about Linked-In - iOS API for it?)

I saw that common answer for similar question is this link:
https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client
But I don't understand what is it and how should I use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client   is a library to link with linkedin and go through http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

and you should go on using that as it will save your time

Comment: for people stumbling on this now q in 2016 - OAuthSwift